# How to fix internet explorer 9 overflow with form elements displayed in a list and "display:table"-based layout

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, width, overflow, forms

I want to build a HTML form with semantic and lightweight markup. Each (label, input) is nested inside a `li` node, child of an `ul`, child of the `form`. As far as the CSS is concerned, any `ul` inside a `form` should be laid out as a table, list items should be laid out as table rows and both labels and inputs as table cells.

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44Lp8/9/)

I've tried the above demo in Chrome 17.0.963.79, Opera 11.61, Safari 5.0.2, Firefox 8.0 and even IE 8.0.7601.17514 and it looks the way I want it to.

However, it seems that IE 9.0.8112.15421 gets some computation wrong: the elements take up the space I want them to, the dev tools show no undesired margin or padding, yet apparently the form containing the `li` (never the `li` itself, nor the `ul`! -- see the demo) gets the width of the label added to it twice, resulting in some **unaccounted-for space**, resulting in a horizontal scrollbar being added to that ancestor. Why is that happening? How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `float:right` to `form li input` and got a result in IE9 that was similar to Chrome.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the trouble. Any idea about the reasons? On the down side, with your fix, the negative margin fix seems to be broken.